# Building JSCIPOpt on Linux (Java interface for Scip)

Tags: java, linux, cmake, java-native-interface, scip

I'm trying to use the [JSCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/JSCIPOpt) "The Java interface for the SCIP Optimization Suite". Following the steps in the INSTALL.md file, I got stuck at 3a) this command line:

```
cmake .. [-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<"Debug" or "Release", default: "Release">]
```

I got this message:

```
cmake .. [-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<"Debug" or "Release", default: "Release">]
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/soukaina/JSCIPOpt-master/build/Release" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

and then I did this and this time I got this message:

```
soukaina@soukaina-Aspire-5250:~/JSCIPOpt-master$ rm -rf build
soukaina@soukaina-Aspire-5250:~/JSCIPOpt-master$ mkdir build
soukaina@soukaina-Aspire-5250:~/JSCIPOpt-master$ cd build
soukaina@soukaina-Aspire-5250:~/JSCIPOpt-master/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found JNI: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/libjawt.so 
-- Java version 1.7.0.85 configured successfully!
-- Found Java: /usr/bin/java (found version "1.7.0.85")
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (include):
  include could not find load file:    
    UseJava    

-- Could NOT find SWIG (missing:  SWIG_EXECUTABLE SWIG_DIR) 
found SCIP library: SCIPOPT_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:96 (add_jar):
  Unknown CMake command "add_jar".


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
SCIPOPT_LIBRARIES
    linked by target "jscip" in directory /home/soukaina/JSCIPOpt-master

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!}
```

The INSTALL.md looks like:

```
....to use/extend the Java interface, you need:

 - SCIP optimization suite
 - Java JDK
 - C compiler
 - CMake
 - SWIG (optional)

The following steps need to be done before compiling the Java interface.   
1) Create a shared library of the [SCIP optimization suite](http://scip.zib.de/#download) by executing     
    make SHARED=true scipoptlib     
in the SCIP optimization suite directory. Afterwards, you will find the library (*.so) in the ./lib directory of the
optimization suite.

2) Create a symbolic link in JSCIPOpt to the library compiled in 1) and to the source directory of SCIP (in the
optimization suite)

    mkdir -p lib;
    cd lib;
    ln -s <SCIP source directory> scipinc
    ln -s <SCIP opt suite directory>/lib/<scip opt library> libscipopt.so

3a) Building JSCIPOpt on Linux.

Compile the interface by executing the following commands:

 - mkdir build
 - cd build
 - cmake .. [-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<"Debug" or "Release", default: "Release">]
 - make

Execute the examples via

 - export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./
 - java -cp scip.jar:examples.jar <"Linear" or "Quadratic" or "Read">
```

Comment: Okay, after you formated your output I have seen that cmake does not find the libscipopt.so in your `JSCIPOpt/lib` directory. Please make sure that you have followed the 1. and 2. point of the INSTALL.md file in JSCIPOpt.

Answer (score 1):

How does the content of your `JSCIPOpt/lib` directory looks like? Do you have the symbolic link pointing to the source directory of SCIP and the other symbolic link pointing to `libscipopt.so`? Could you download and install the latest version of Java JDK?

I also think that you misunderstood the

```
cmake .. [-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=<"Debug" or "Release", default: "Release">]
```

For example, compiling JSCIPOpt in debug mode requires to execute this command:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

**EDIT:**

You did not set the symbolic links correctly. Basically, you need to execute these commands:

```
cd JSCIPOpt
mkdir lib; cd lib
ln -s /home/soukaina/scipoptsuite-4.0.0/scip-4.0.0/src scipinc
ln -s /home/soukaina/scipoptsuite-4.0.0/lib/libscipopt.so libscipopt.so
cd ..
mkdir build; cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot for yr reply! ...................................................................then, when I put " make SHARED=true scipoptlib", I got 2 files: libscipopt.so & libscipopt-4.0.0.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt.so.......PLZ, when you say pointing to the source directory, is this mean this path "scipoptsuite-4.0.0/scip-4.0.0/src",,,,,,,,,,,,,,the second symolic link to libscipopt.so I type like this : "ln -s  /home/soukaina/scipoptsuite-4.0.0/lib/libscipopt   libscipopt.so"

Comment: I added commands that you need to execute to my answer above.